# Passing a list from Controller to View in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I have an Index action method as follows.I am passing a list of Providers to the View.

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Provider providerList = new Provider();
        List<Provider> providers = DAL.GetListofProviders.ToList();
        return View(providers);
    }
```

In the View,I have the following code to receive the List of Providers.

```
     @model IEnumerable<DEMO_JAN14.Models.Provider>

@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

 <head>
<title>LIST OF PROVIDERS</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <tr>     
        <th>Provider Type</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Certification</th>
        <th>Specialization</th>
        <th>SSN</th>
        <th>Facility Name</th>
        <th>Contact No</th>
        <th>Contact Email</th>
        <th></th>  
      </tr>

<tbody data-bind="foreach: viewmodel">
  <tr>
        <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: ProviderType"></td>
        <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
        <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
        <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: Certification"></>
        <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: Specialization"></td>
        <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: SSN"></td>
        <td class="col-lg-4" data-bind="text: FacilityName"></td>
        <td class="col-lg-4" data-bind="text: ContactNumber"></td>
        <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: ContactEmail"></td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-danger" id="del" onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete');" data-bind="attr: { href: '/Provider/Delete/' + ProviderID }"> Delete </a>
        </td>
    </tr> 
</tbody>
```

I see the list of Providers in the controller

[image]

But I dont see the same list in the view as shown

[image]

Am I doing something wrong.Please guide me in the right directions.Thanks.

Comment: try `IList<Provider> providers = DAL.GetListofProviders.ToList();`

Comment: Hey,Thanks for the reply.But,I am still not seeing the list of providers in the View.

Comment: in view file use @model List<DEMO_JAN14.Models.Provider>.

Comment: I just did that.I am still not getting the provider list data.Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try `<tbody data-bind="foreach: Provider">` ?
Sorry I can only suggest things, as i'm not able to debug your solution.

Comment: Hey,As can be seen from the images above,I am not seeing the list of providers in the view.I can see it in the controller.

Comment: It's perfectly normal, that you only see the base class when hovering over IEnumerable<DEMO_JAN14.Models.Provider

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate like this (using your code)

```
@model IEnumerable<DEMO_JAN14.Models.Provider>

@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<head>
<title>LIST OF PROVIDERS</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <tr>     
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ProviderType)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)</th>
        ...
      </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
  <tr>
        <td class="col-lg-2">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProviderType)</td>
        <td class="col-lg-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)</td>
        ...
  </tr> 
</table>   
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I can do that,but I have to use knockout for binding.Could you please guide me on that.

Comment: No sorry I've never used knockout. The only thing I don't understand, is why you are typing: `<tbody data-bind="foreach: viewmodel">` instead of `<tbody data-bind="foreach: Provider">`

Comment: Ok .. Thanks.I dont think we can bind it directly.Knockout requires a viewmodel I believe.

Answer (score 0):

To check the count of the providers list inside the view use the following property

```
@Model
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view you can iterate like this on the items, and for example am displaying `FirstName` of each `Provider` in the List:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
 <h1>@item.FirstName </h1>
}
```

Using your html:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: viewmodel">
@foreach(var item in Model)
 {
  <tr>
        <td class="col-lg-2">@item.ProviderType</td>
        <td class="col-lg-1">@item.FirstName</td>
        ........................................
        ........................................
        // and so on other properties
        <td><a class="btn btn-danger" id="del" onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete');" href="@Url.Action("Delete","Provider")+ item.ProviderID }"> Delete </a>
 </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: I am not getting the provider list.Could you guide on where I might be going wrong?

Comment: @AbhishekKS you need to iterate on ``@Model`` can you check by doing: ``<h1>@Model.Count()</h1>`` in View that what it outputs on page?

Comment: Hey,The Model.Count is showing correctly.Bur How Do I bind each provider data using knockout.

Answer (score 0):

you can't access the razor Model object via knockout

you need to receive your data as json result

please refer to this article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424642/Customer-KnockoutJS-and-MVC-demo-using-JSON